# java call c++ multi threads library, not release threads which created by c++

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a java process, which call a c++ .so lib, java code like this:

```
com.bj58.spider.faiss.Index index;  //create by swig, real c++ obj
index.search(query.length, q.cast(), k, distances.cast(), labels.cast());  //call c++ lib,\
                                               func search will use multi threads(openmp) run results.
```

index.search is a c++ interface, Underlying call use openmp to multiple thread running for loop.

the result is OK, but I found as soon as execute index.search, the number of threads which in the java process will grow. And it never released. how to solve the problem?

Comment: Is it possible OpenMP has created a pool of worker threads in order to reuse them for a future call? Are the threads doing anything or are they parked?

Comment: If you mean that threads created by OpenMP under C++ aren't immediately available when returning to Java, yes, most OpenMP implementations do this, to be prepared for entering a parallel region again.  Typical default spin time is 100 ms.  This is controlled by OMP_WAIT_POLICY as well as proprietary environment variables.